# Windows 7 is not mounting one of the partitions

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, partitioning

I used to have 3 primary partitions on my drive, and windows was installed on one of them. The other two are for recovery and for personal files. Just yesterday, I resized the personal files partiton, and created two logical partitions on the free space. In one of the logical partitions I installed windows 7.

As soon as I boot up windows for the first time, it asks to do a disk check on that primary personal files partition. I skiped it cause I was in a hurry, and when I get into windows, I see that the partition is not mounted. All other partitions show up under *My Computer* with no problem, but this one doesn't. If I go to disk management, it does see the partition and claims its healthy.

So I reboot. Windows asks to do the disk check again, and I let him this time. It performs the check and finds no errors. When I get in to windows again, it still doesn't see the partition.

What's going on?

It does see the other primary partition (the one where windows was originally installed). And it sees both logical partitions. But the primary partition with my personal files just isn't getting mounted. Though disk management claims it to  be OK

All partitions are NTFS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the drive is fine, but it just isn't mounting, follow these instructions:

Go to computer management (Right click Computer / My Computer), then click "Manage"

"Expand Storage" > "Disk Management", and right click on the drive you wish to change.

Click on "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and click Add.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Do Assign Letter, not mount in a folder!)

Comment: Wow, that was ridiculously simple. Thanks a lot. Wonder why it didn't assign a mount point automatically in the first place.

Comment: There are some situations where it doesn't auto assign. I think the most common is when it was previously mounted to a letter but the letter is now used by something else - It would rather you assigned a new one than automatically use the next.... Check your event log if interested as there may be an entry there.

Comment: Now that I think of it, is it unwise to assign it to my user's folder instead of to a letter? It would actually be pretty convenient to me

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you wrote... can you rephrase please and I will be happy to answer...

Comment: I wanted to assign the "Personal Files" partition to be mounted in a folder instead of a drive letter. That way I could mount it in my "Users" folder. I was asking if that would be a bad idea. I still want to do it, but I realised it's not that easy, since windows won't let me empty the Users folder, and I can only mount the partition in an epmty folder.

Comment: Personally, I don't like mounting drives in folders however there is nothing wrong with it... as long as permissions are ok, there shouldn't be a problem